# How can I extrude the surface of Can patterns on the top view of the can evenly?

Tags: modeling, vertices, subdivision-surface

[image: 2]

[image: 1]

Hello, so I wanna make this can (second pic) and working on recreating the top view right now. The problem now comes with geometry/vertex problems as I assume while extruding. I want to extrude an area in the middle basically the "knob" of the can, but once I do extrude the shape and turn the "subdiviosion surface modifier" on (to give it a rounder shape) the surface kind of turns out weird like in the first picture.
What needs to be taken care of so the selected face gets extruded evenly?

Best

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need additional edge loops across the shape, like that:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this question and experimented a little with an additional technique.  Because you want a lot of fine detail on the can top that is only raised a little bit, you could try using a normal map or bump map.

Creating a normal map is a bit tricky if you don't use Photoshop or the free image editor Gimp, because you can only use certain colours.  The other thing is that you have to experiment with the material editor to get the right settings.[image]

Obviously, you could combine it with the extrude method and get a better effect.